# Calculating the eccentricity of an orbiting object, knowing it's speed at a particular distance

Tags: orbital-motion

Let's say a very small asteroid, the mass of 12 500 kg is orbiting the Sun at the distance of exactly 2 AU and the velocity 19 700 m/s. If needed - it is going 49 degrees from the general direction of left, the angle is facing downwards, and looking right above the orbital plane. Is it possible to calculate the eccentricity of the asteroid?

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity the definition of eccentricity is given. I do not think that  from the parameters you give  one can derive eccentricity.

Comment: @anna Yes, it's crucial to have the radial & velocity *vectors*, not just their magnitudes.

Answer (score 4):

When you know the position and velocity vector of the asteroid
($\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}$), then you can calculate the [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Mathematical_definition)
$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{L}-mk\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
where $m$ is the mass of the asteroid,
$\mathbf{p}=m\mathbf{v}$ is its momentum,
$\mathbf{L}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$ is its angular momentum,
$\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is the unit vector in radial direction,
and $k=GM_\text{sun}m$ is from Newton's gravitational law.

The result $\mathbf{A}$ will be a vector pointing in perihelion direction,
and from its magnitude $A$ you get the eccentricity by
$e=\frac{A}{mk}$.
(You see, the asteroid mass $m$ cancels out. So you don't need to know it.)